# Tag pluralization

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed that we are inconsistent on tag plural forms. The question here is do we want to have plurals or do we want to have singular (or don't we care).

As soon as this is decided I will create a list of the wrong ones so a CM can rename them (afaics none of us has the rep yet to do so ourselves AND you can't use 'singular' if 'singulars' already exists and visa-versa so retagging all questions won't work).

I'm unsure how much useless nitpicking this is so if you feel that **shouldn't be done either way, downvote the Q** :)

Comment: is the intention of this post for tags like [tag:firefox-extension] - [tag:vim-plugin] etc?

Comment: Once we reach consensus on the way we'll do this, we can arrange with CMs or pro tems to go through all of our current tags and clean them up - we shouldn't take any action on changing any of these *until* we have reached consensus.

Comment: @Flyk yes. As well as "-service", "-server", "-plugin", "email"

Comment: Related: [Pluralization of tags describing an app type](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2535/60)

Answer (score 4):

I generally use the singular for uncountable nouns (no choice anyway) and for general concepts that generally arise in a single instance, and the plural for countable objects when there are generally potentially many such objects. As a rule of thumb, would you say that the question is

- “about X” (→ singular): [networking](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking), [photography](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography)
- “about an X” (→ singular): [database](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database), [ide](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide)
- “about the X” (→ singular): [command-line](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line), [display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display)
- “about Xes” (→ plural): [text-editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), [monitors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors)
- “about doing something with Xes” (→ plural): [databases](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases), [files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files)

As you can see from the examples, there's quite a bit of ambiguity.

Some tags have to be singular (uncountable nouns), so we can't systematically use a plural. Other tags don't really work in the singular (e.g. [file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) — you never work with one file, always with *files*, plus [file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) to a Unix person looks like it's about the `file` utility), so we can't systematically use the singular either. No Stack Exchange site that I've seen has established any kind of consistent rule. [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags) comes closest to my personal preferences even though I wasn't behind the tag names; it has:

- [encryption](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption), [web-application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application), [authentication](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication), [cryptography](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), [network](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network), [hash](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash), [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser), [malware](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malware), [email](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), [privacy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy), [penetration-test](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penetration-test), …
- [passwords](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwords), [certificates](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates), [attacks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attacks), [firewalls](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firewalls), …

We shouldn't try to enforce a singular-only policy, as it would force some bad tag names. Let tags arise naturally in either form, and rename if we find a strong argument to rename.

Comment: On travel.SE we have managed to pretty successfully establish a consistency rule. I wrote a post on how to choose tag names based on more than just dumb singular vs. plural but I'm not sure where it is ... here it is: ***[Tags should be plurals (with a few caveats)](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/336)***

Answer (score -1):

I suggest we use singular form always.

Because one looks for one program not for many.

Also: singular is always meaningful while plural makes no sense for stuff like "audio" or "command-line"

Comment: Humm, then we will probably be an exception. AFAIK, most SE sites use plural forms. @Flyk, you're around on many sites: Is this consistent?

Comment: On the sites I use at least, it's always server, not servers, installation, not installations, network, not networks, etc... Do you have any specifics in mind so I can evaluate those?

Comment: Right, I'm seeing what you mean - it's not a definitive policy on how to deal with these but it does lean towards using plurals *where it makes sense* - so we wouldn't go changing [tag:audio] to audios and [tag:video] to videos but we would change *-extension to *-extensions and *-plugin to *-plugins

Comment: As I pointed out on chat: [AskUbuntu], [SU], and [Android.SE] tags mostly use plurals *except for standing terms* (like the examples you've used, and which would also include audio, video, browser). It's e.g. always driverS, deviceS, appS, settingS, notificationS, etc.

Comment: @Izzy otoh: SO has no consistency on this whatsoever